# How to get the job details in Windows Azure Backup agent?

Tags: powershell, azure, backup

I've install Windows Azure Backup agent and create a scheduled backup. When scheduled backup is executed and completed, I will receive an email notification using task scheduler, event log, and powershell, stated the backup is successful, with warnings, or with errors. It is working but I want to include in my email the job details like backup file items and size, duration time of execution, cause of warnings and errors, and etc. I have only this code for getting the path of the file that need to be backup.

```
(Get-OBPolicy | get-OBFileSpec | Where-Object {$_.IsExclude -eq $False}).FileSpec
```

It will generate something like this `C:\Program Files`,`C:\Temp`.

Please help me or give me a useful link I can use. Thank you.